# How to declare an array in visual studio?

Tags: c++, windows

First, I write this code at vscode, it can be executed. Then I copy to visual studio, showing this error.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s = "abcdefg";
    int arr[s.size()];
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code as an image, copy and paste the code into the post itself.

Comment: Please provide the entire code instead of photo so that it will be easy to debug for other to help u.

Comment: You don't declare an array in Visual Studio.  You use Visual Studio to write C++ programs, in which you might declare arrays.  In your case `bitset <7> h[pt_size]` is illegal C++: it actually has SEVERAL different errors.  Read the documentation for correct usage: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/bitset/

Comment: You may want to read this: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12149471)

Answer (score 1):

In C++ the size of array must be a compile time constant(`constant expression)`. So the following is incorrect:

```
int n = 10;
int arr[n]; //incorrect
```

Correct way to write the above is:

```
const int n = 10;
int arr[n]; //correct
```

So the error

> Expression must have constant value

indicates this error since `pt_size` must be a constant expression(integral).

From [cpp](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/)

> The elements field within square brackets [], representing the number of elements in the array, must be a constant expression, since arrays are blocks of static memory whose size must be determined at compile time, before the program runs.